# Remaining number of open files in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, ulimit

`ulimit -a` tells me I have a limit of 1024 open files, which is the default on my distro. Is there a way to show how many of these are currently used, or how many are remaining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This limit apply per process.

One way to get the number of open files per process would be on Linux or Solaris:

```
for i in /proc/*/fd
do
    [ -r $i ] && printf "%6d : %d\n" $(basename $(dirname $i)) $(ls $i | wc -l)
done
```

Comment: If I start a shell, isn't this limit inherited to all child processes which I do further start from this shell?

Comment: Or more exactly, is the number of the remaining open files inherited?

Comment: No. Each subprocess starts with the full number of available fds. What is inherited is that limit, which can be reduced (or raised if you have the privileges).